# Unity Start nog called on real build

Tags: c#, build, unity-game-engine

I've made a dice app as a project to learn to work with unity (it was so good in my eyes that I put it on the google play store) but when I downloaded it from there, the Start function of at least 2 scripts isn't called and I have no idea whether the other Start functions are being called.

Here you can see 2 of the Start functions that aren't called

```
void Start()
{
    light = light.GetComponent<Light>();
    GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    rawImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();
    isLockMode = false;
    rawImage.texture = getIconLock(isLockMode);
}

void Start()
{
    Screen.fullScreen = false;
    Dice.AddDie();
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    GlobalConfig.onShowShadowsChanged += onShadowsEnabledChange;
}
```

They work when I use Unity Remote on my smartphone and they also work when I just use unity without the remote...

the first script is attached to a UI element and the second script is attached to an empty GameObject called 'App'

It's also even more weird because they used to work but then I switched pc's (but used the same code).
I think something is wrong with the building itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem, the build was generating two files, an .apk and an other .odb or somethingl ike that (might be another extension). I had to untick 'split application binary' in the player settings